# Printing Vectors - Empty output

Tags: c++, vector

I just begun with C++ and im learning about vectors. made a loop to add values into the vector table and then tried to print it out by using:

```
std::copy(multi_array.begin(), multi_array.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
```

but that prints an empty string on the console window.

here's the code:

```
  vector<int> multi_array;
  for(int v=0;v <= 3; v++){
    multi_array.push_back(v);
  }
  std::copy(multi_array.begin(), multi_array.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
                      ^^^
```

to write `int`s. The first template argument must be the type to be printed.

To avoid future trouble like this check out [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "))
```

try to use:

```
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "))
```

You should pass to template the type of vector. Does it work :) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your ints in vector are getting casted to chars, and chars 0,1,2,3 are not printable, that's why you get empty output.

You need to put printable characters, to see actual output.

```
for (char v = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++v) {
    mutli_array.push_back(v);
}
```

Or you need to specify valid type to print:

```
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You might look into some C++ tutorials or a udemy course in it. A more straightforward way to print than using the copy function is this:

```
vector<int> multi_array;
for(int v=0;v <= 3; v++){
    multi_array.push_back(v);
    cout << multi_array.back() << " ";
}

cout << endl;
```

Don't forget to #include iostream

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the right data-type in the `ostream_iterator` defintion :

```
std::copy(multi_array.begin(), multi_array.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```